# Google Sign-in for websites - How to get token

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, google-authentication, google-oauth

I am using Google sign-in for Websites. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Per documentation, under the function `onSignIn(googleUser)`, I get an ID_Token using `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token`

But apparently this is not the `access_token` that I can use in future to revoke. How can I get the `access_token` on the client side from googleUser object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after several hours of breaking head, I got an answer from a Google developer.

Use the following line. Passing `true` in `getAuthResponse` function returns the `access_token` and `expiry`. This is the recommended solution.

```
googleUser.getAuthResponse(true).access_token;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the `googleUser` in the call back. You will find `Zi` property in that. In that object you will find `access_token` and `expire` times as well.

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    console.log(googleUser.Zi);
}
```